# Equivalent onAuthRequired callback for Safari Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, basic-authentication, safari-extension

I have both Chrome and Safari extensions.  They allow users to log into a website that is protected with basic HTTP authentication with a single click.

In Chrome, I am able to hook into an `onAuthRequired` listener/callback in order to authorize a user for a page which is protected by HTTP basic authentication.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Safari? In the past I have used an `XMLHttpRequest` object to pre-authorize a user, but this does not work correctly for all websites.

Code example in Chrome:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener( function(details,callback) {

  if (details.url.match(basic_auth_url)) {
    callback({"authCredentials":{"username":basic_auth_username,"password":basic_auth_password}})
    chrome.tabs.update(basic_auth_tab_id, {url: basic_auth_redirect_url}); 
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}, 
{"urls":["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]}, ["asyncBlocking"]);
```

Comment: were you able to get the equivalent of 'onAuthRequired' in Safari?

Comment: @techcraver no, I haven't attempted to solve this issue since I posted the question -- please post an answer here if you figure out a solution! :)

Comment: did anyone ever found its solution? @ professormeowingtons  @teechcraver  I am also stuck with the same issue.. or safari din't updated anything on this, even after so many years..

Comment: @user5821368 no, in fact I quit the company I was working at to try to solve this :D (not due to this problem though) wish I could be more help.

Comment: @professormeowingtons Thank you for your reply :)